# VFS Italy in London

Tags: uk, schengen, italy, vfs-global

The Italy VFS for UK Residents insist that the appliacnt should have the required funds in the Current Account. On the other hand UK Banks insist that you maintain the minimum amount in the Current account and have the major part in the 'hidden' savings account.
My child has caught in a dilemma over this. Will her visa be rejected due to the reason the funds are available in the savings account?

Another one. The University letter should be a signed one. My daughter got a signed letter by email and she got it printed and presented. VFS says it cannot be accepted as the signature is not 'wet' !

Last one. All the additional requirements pop up after submitting the online visa application. New 'must haves' are showing up in the check list which is sent to you after submitting the application.

Comment: What is your daughter's nationality, and what visa is she applying for?

Comment: Won't the bank issue a statement showing balances in both the "current" and "savings" accounts? It could be accompanied by your daughter's statement that the bank requires her to maintain only the minimum amount in the current account.

Comment: I've never seen a UK bank impose such a restriction on a current account, nor do I believe that UK immigration has a problem with the accounts a sum of money is held in. This seems more like a misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass the question concerns a visa application for Italy, so policies of UK immigration authorities are only indirectly relevant.

Comment: She is a Sri Lankan having British residence. She is applying for Italian visa.

Comment: It’s not a restriction by the bank, but a caution expressed by the bank.

Comment: The whole issue is that vfs do not guide the applicants fully. Vfs has come across vast number of genuine applicants who have faulted in the application process and vfs only could  guide them. Instead once you visit the vfs Centre they start exploring the reasons why and how vfs could reject the application!

Comment: @phoog My mistake, but my comment stands for the Italians. From what I see on this site, VFS don't always give accurate advice. Were I applying I'd submit both statements and add a note in a covering letter.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass agreed.  VFS often gives confusing or incorrect guidance to applicants, and I've seen cases mentioned where they've improperly refused to accept applications.  As Felician seems to suggest, it may be because they have misinterpreted the reasons underlying refusals of other applications, or it may be because they see their role as a gatekeeper to prevent "bad" applications from reaching a country's visa officers while lacking a full understanding of the requirements.

Comment: By the way why cant the VFS say in their website that they only accept "wet signatures"?